# Apex: error when creating a form

Tags: oracle-apex

I'm learning Apex, and I was very motivated when I went through few tutorials but as soon as I tried to create my 1st plain form it is crashing and can't google any thing useful.

I'm trying to create a page using Form on a Table template to get a front end to access my new table but I keep getting

```
ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into 
("APEX_050100"."WWV_FLOW_MENU_OPTIONS"."SHORT_NAME")
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
Radek

```
CREATE TABLE RRDefinitions
( definition_id NUMBER          NOT NULL,
  definition_description    VARCHAR(45)     NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT    pk_definition_id PRIMARY KEY (definition_id)
);


CREATE SEQUENCE definition_id_seq START WITH 100;

CREATE OR REPLACE trigger BI_RRDefinitions  
  before insert on RRDefinitions              
  for each row 
begin  
  if :NEW.definition_id is null then
    select definition_id_SEQ.nextval into :NEW.definition_id from dual;
  end if;
end;
```

Comment: Fresh installation? Pretty sure this will work fine on apex.oracle.com

Comment: Yes, i tried that on apex.oracle.com and that's broken also. I must be doing something wrong. Tried also creating a "Create Form and List View"  on apex.oracle.com and I got another error ORA-20001: unique constraint (APEX_050100.WWV_FLOW_STEPS_PK) violated using my new table. I also tried to create a List View form using another Demo table and it failed with the same error. It appears that you need some very specific sequence of options checked to get that working, no idea, looked easy on a tutorial. I'm trying a mobile template vs desktop app maybe that is more specific .....

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what happened but using my cell and Firefox there I was able to create a page. PC works every now and then as long as I don't use breadcrumbs and if I don't create a menu item entry.  My conclusion is my environment is either old, obsolete or messed up will reinstall from scratch. Thank you for your help